# How to extract the Email-Address using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract the 'email' using selenium. I want to get the `value="raipiwro@squizzy.net"` directly from the box. How can i do this ?

Website link: https://www.squizzy.de/

[image: how to get value="raipiwro@squizzy.net]

Answer (score 1):

Helloww, you're trying to get the attribute `value` of an `element`, so we should do that:

```
driver.find_element("tag name", 'input').get_attribute('value')
```

First we get the `element`, then, get it's `value` attribute which is the email

Answer (score 0):

To extract the email address using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='mail']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='mail']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```